# iPhone 6s - Calendars and contacts - birthday information

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 6s.  I want to put birthdays in my contacts however I don't want them to show up in my calendar.  I've tried everything to stop it but nothing short of taking the birthdays out of my contacts works!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Confirmed it works

<strike>Did you try:</strike>

```
- Open the Calendar app
- Click on 'Calendars' at the bottom
- uncheck all birthday calendars
```

The birthday calendar should be under Others at the bottom

[image]

[image]